# Problem calling withdraw from WBNB inside the contract

Tags: solidity, wrapped-tokens

I have these to functions:

```
function stake(address _token, uint256 amount) external payable {
    address sender = msg.sender;
    address receiver = address(this);
    IERC20 token = IERC20(_token);

    if (_token == weth) {
        // ETH deposit
        require(msg.value > 0, "No ETH sent");
        stakedAmountPerToken[_token] = stakedAmountPerToken[_token].add(amount);
        userData[sender].userBalance[_token] = userData[sender].userBalance[_token].add(amount);
        emit Staked(_token, sender, amount);
        if (!isUser[sender]) {
            users.push(sender);
            isUser[sender] = true;
        }
    } else {
        uint256 allowance = token.allowance(sender, receiver);
        require(allowance >= amount, "Insufficient token allowance");

        token.transferFrom(sender, receiver, amount);
        userData[sender].userBalance[_token] = userData[sender].userBalance[_token].add(amount);
        if (!isUser[sender]) {
            users.push(sender);
            isUser[sender] = true;
        }
        emit Staked(_token, sender, amount);
    }
}

function withdraw(address token, uint256 amount) external payable {
    address payable sender = payable(msg.sender);
    require(isUser[sender], "User has no staked balance");
    require(userData[sender].userBalance[token] >= amount, "Insufficient balance for withdrawal");

    if (token == weth) {
        // Convert WETH to ETH
        IWETH(weth).withdraw(amount);
        sender.transfer(amount);
    } else {
        // Token withdrawal
        require(IERC20(token).transfer(sender, amount), "Token transfer failed");
    }

    userData[sender].userBalance[token] = userData[sender].userBalance[token].sub(amount);

    if (userData[sender].userBalance[token] == 0) {
        isUser[sender] = false;
    }

    emit Withdrawed(token, sender, amount);
}
```

The way i interact with the IWETH in the `stake` works but when i call the `withdraw` if the requisites from the reverts are filled i got this error:

`Error Message: Called function does not exist in the contract`

Can i have a hint from someone over this?

*EDIT*

[image: The deposit function works]

[image: But the withdraw doesn't]

Comment: You ll need to share some more data like the input parameters and the rest of the code. Are you sure you are passing the correct parameters? Also withdraw isnt suppose to accept eth so it shouldnt be market as payable.

Comment: The params are okey i'm using tenderly to simulate. The payabçe was a suggestion from chatGPT.

Answer (score 0):

```
function withdraw(address token, uint256 amount)
```

Please make sure the token is a contract address, if the token is an external account address, the call will fail.

Comment: The problem was lack of fallback functions.